# UPS: Why TimeInTransit for UPS Freight API doesn't work?

Tags: api, ups

Does anyone knows how to get Time In Transit for UPS Freight Shipping. In developers guide I found instructions to specify TimeInTransitIndicator option:

> Presence of the tag indicates Time in Transit information is requested
>   and will be returned.

But there is no any /FreightRateResponse/TimeInTransit tag in UPS' response.

Also there is no such tag `<xsd:element name="TimeInTransit" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>` in FreightRateWebServiceSchema.xsd file from the UPS' developer's kit in response tag `<xsd:element name="FreightRateResponse">`

Does anyone know how to get `TimeInTransit` for Freight API? Would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked UPS support and got the answer:

> The < freightRate:TimeInTransit > will only be returned when posting a
>   request to the production URL.
>
> Your key will need to be approved for production access for the Ground
>   Freight Rating API before you will be able to post successfully to the
>   production URL.
>
> The .xsd files and WSDL in the developer tool kit are designed to
>   deliver this element in production without editing, so what you have
>   observed with the schema files is by design.

And this is example response with TimeInTransit tag from UPS support https://gist.github.com/antongorodezkiy/5973888